# Why can't my Controller see the service I added?

Tags: php, symfony, service, symfony4

I'm having difficulties adding a service/helper in my controller. Since the new Symfony4 it should autowire the service as far as I know, but still something goes wrong.
The error I get is:

> InvalidArgumentException
>
> Cannot determine controller argument for "App\Controller\KibbleController::index()": the $dinoHelper argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface: "App\Service\DinoHelper".

I've tried adding the service inside the controller using new DinoHelper, but with minimal effect.

*src/Controller/KibbleController*

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\SimpleKibble;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Exception;
use App\Service\DinoHelper;

class KibbleController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route "/"
     * @param Request $request
     * @param DinoHelper $dinoHelper
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request, DinoHelper $dinoHelper)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('Dino', TextType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Submit'])
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            $dinoHelper->getKibbleEntity($data['Dino']);
```

*src/Service/DinoHelper.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\Dodo;
use App\Entity\Dilo;
use App\Entity\Raptor;

class DinoHelper
{

    public function getKibbleEntity(string $name)
    {
        switch ($name)
        {
            case 'Dodo' :
                $dinoEntity = new Dodo();
                break;
            case 'Dilo' :
                $dinoEntity = new Dilo();
                break;
            case 'Raptor' :
                $dinoEntity = new Raptor();
                break;
        }
        return isset($dinoEntity) ? $dinoEntity : null;

    }
}
```

*services.yaml*

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'en'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Comment: Please show your `services.yml` file

Comment: Forgot about that. Added it.

Comment: You might would to change resource: `'../src/Controller'` to resource: `'../src/Controller/*'` to register controllers as a services with properly tag

Comment: @Chrzanek I tried it but it didn't have effect on this exception.

Comment: Do you see your service when you execute `debug:autowiring` from the console?

Comment: how are you autoloading your classes? Is your composer autoload setup and dumped ?